# Doctrine Extension Loggable on single or multiple tables (for performance)

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

I have roughly 60 entities. All of them have some fields which are loggable. I expect roughly 1000 fields in total to be logged. Let's estimate that each field changes 10 times on average. I'm setting up a SaaS, so I'm expecting more than one hundred "projects". We are talking therefore about a 1 million records as order of magnitude (growing to 100 millions-1 billion if the thing is successful)

Having used Symfony2+Doctrine2 it should be fairly easy to migrate to MySQL (current DB) to a more performing ones, and the growth will not happen overnight.

So the question is: shall I use a single table (as default) to log all entities change, or shall I set a table for each entity? In the end this will reduce just by a factor of 60 (tops) the number of lines in the table. Considering that it's way more difficult to maintain 60 tables than one, what would you advice?